# Why is my for loop executing more than once for each time a value is inputted?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a programming assignment that's asking me to have the user input 10 (or less) integers and put them in an array, then take the average of them and output it.  If they input a period, the program should stop asking for integers and do the averaging.

My problem is that whenever the user inputs an integer, the for loop executes more than once.

My code is below.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
    int[] intArr = new int[10];

    int entered;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for(entered = 0; entered < 10; entered++){
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");

        int input = br.read();

        if(input == '.') break;

        else{
            intArr[entered] = input;
        }
    }

    int total = 0;
    for(int i : intArr){
        total += i;
    }

    System.out.println("Average: " + total/entered);
    System.out.println("Entered: " + entered);
```

Comment: Probably `br.read()` is reading the enter key press.

Comment: `input == '.'` input is an int , not a `char`, use `readLine()`

Comment: Alright.  I switched it to readLine(), but now how do I read that as a char?  I can't cast it.

Comment: @user2958237 with `line.trim().charAt(0) == '.'`

Comment: There we go!  I tried charAt, but I didn't think of using trim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String input = br.readLine()` to read an entire line.

To check for `"."`, use `if (input.equals(".")) { ... }`.
(check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) if you want to know why you have to use `.equals()` instead of `==` for Strings)

Finally, to convert the input to an integer, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java).

Comment: Yup, I know about the equals(); Andrey helped me solve it above.  I'll mark this as my answer, anyways.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (entered = 0; entered < 10; entered++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
    String str = br.readLine();
    if (".".equals(str)) {
        break;
    }
    int input = Integer.valueOf(str);
    intArr[entered] = input;
}
```

Comment: P.S. Don't forget to handle thrown exceptions

Comment: Thanks!  I added a try catch into my code.  Originally, I just threw it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Its Really Simple 
First let Me Explain You Why Its Happening 
Ok the read() function reads first char of the input value and rest of line is stored in buffer
so when you enter any integer 
for example: 1
1 is stored in variable and '\n'which java by defaults adds to a input value gets stored in buffer
so in next iteration of loop 
it reads the char '\n' from buffer as input value and moves to next iteration

EXAMPLE 2:
If In Your Program We Enter Input As 12
It Skips Two Iterations 
Coz Firstly It Stores 1 At The Time Of Input 
In Next Iteration It Takes value 2 of previous input as input for this time
In Further Next Iteration It Takes '\n' 
and then moves to next iteration at which their is no character left in memory so it asks you to input

Note:::
read() functions return character so even if user enters 5 while calculation ASCII Code Of 10 will be used that is 53 not one creating problems

FIX:::

```
int[] intArr = new int[10];
int entered;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
for (entered = 0; entered < 10; entered++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");

    String input = br.readLine();

    if (input.equals(".")) {
        break;
    } else {
        intArr[entered] = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
}
int total = 0;
for (int i: intArr) {
    total += i;
}
System.out.println("Average: " + total / entered);
System.out.println("Entered: " + entered);
```